# Rust benchmark optimized out

Tags: hashmap, rust, benchmarking

I am trying to benchmark getting keys from a Rust hash map. I have the following benchmark:

```
#[bench]
fn rust_get(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let (hash, keys) =
        get_random_hash::<HashMap<String, usize>>(&HashMap::with_capacity, &rust_insert_fn);
    let mut keys = test::black_box(keys);
    b.iter(|| {
        for k in keys.drain(..) {
            hash.get(&k);
        }
    });
}
```

where `get_random_hash` is defined as:

```
fn get_random_hash<T>(
    new: &Fn(usize) -> T,
    insert: &Fn(&mut T, String, usize) -> (),
) -> (T, Vec<String>) {
    let mut keys = Vec::with_capacity(HASH_SIZE);
    let mut hash = new(HASH_CAPACITY);
    for i in 0..HASH_SIZE {
        let k: String = format!("{}", Uuid::new_v4());
        keys.push(k.clone());
        insert(&mut hash, k, i);
    }
    return (hash, keys);
}
```

and `rust_insert_fn` is:

```
fn rust_insert_fn(map: &mut HashMap<String, usize>, key: String, value: usize) {
    map.insert(key, value);
}
```

However, when I run the benchmark, it is clearly optimized out:

```
test benchmarks::benchmarks::rust_get        ... bench:           1 ns/iter (+/- 0)
```

I thought `test::black_box would solve the problem but it doesn't look like it does. I have even tried wrapping the`hash.get(&k`) in the for loop with`test::black_box` but that still optimizes the code. How should I correctly get the code to run without being optimized out?

EDIT - Even the following does optimizes out the get operation:

```
#[bench]
fn rust_get(b: &mut Bencher) {
  let (hash, keys) = get_random_hash::<HashMap<String, usize>>(&HashMap::with_capacity, &rust_insert_fn);
  let mut keys = test::black_box(keys);
  b.iter(|| {
    let mut n = 0;
    for k in keys.drain(..) {
      hash.get(&k);
      n += 1;
    };
    return n;
  });
}
```

Interestingly, the following benchmarks work:

```
#[bench]
fn rust_get_random(b: &mut Bencher) {
  let (hash, _) = get_random_hash::<HashMap<String, usize>>(&HashMap::with_capacity, &rust_insert_fn);
  b.iter(|| {
    for _ in 0..HASH_SIZE {
      hash.get(&format!("{}", Uuid::new_v4()));
    }
  });
}

#[bench]
fn rust_insert(b: &mut Bencher) {
  b.iter(|| {
    let mut hash = HashMap::with_capacity(HASH_CAPACITY);
    for i in 0..HASH_SIZE {
      let k: String = format!("{}", Uuid::new_v4());
      hash.insert(k, i);
    }
  });
}
```

but this also does not:

```
#[bench]
fn rust_del(b: &mut Bencher) {
  let (mut hash, keys) = get_random_hash::<HashMap<String, usize>>(&HashMap::with_capacity, &rust_insert_fn);
  let mut keys = test::black_box(keys);
  b.iter(|| {
    for k in keys.drain(..) {
      hash.remove(&k);
    };
  });
}
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d0dd3b9a1c2e8403e441820c62e6e3d7) is the full gist.

Comment: FWIW, I always return a value from the closure passed to `Bencher::iter`. I'd try aggregating the values of `hash.get(&k)` somehow (or even just a counter) and return that.

Comment: That didn't work (see edit)

Answer (score 8):

> How does a compiler optimizer work?

An optimizer is nothing more than a pipeline of [analyses and transformations](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html). Each individual analysis or transformation is relatively simple, and the optimal order to apply them is unknown and generally determined by heuristics.

> How does this affect my benchmark?

Benchmarks are complicated in that in general you wish to measure optimized code, but at the same time some analyses or transformations may remove the code you were interested in rendering the benchmark useless.

It is therefore important to have a passing acquaintance with the analyses and transformation passes of the particular optimizer you are using so as to be able to understand:

- which ones are undesirable,
- how to foil them.

As mentioned, most passes are relatively simple, and therefore foiling them is relatively simple as well. The difficulty lies in the fact that there is a hundred or more of them and you have to know which one is kicking in to be able to foil it.

> What optimizations am I running afoul of?

There are a few specific optimizations which very often play often with benchmarks:

- [Constant Propagation](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#constprop-simple-constant-propagation): allows evaluating part of the code at compile-time,
- [Loop Invariant Code Motion](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#licm-loop-invariant-code-motion): allows lifting the evaluation of some piece of code outside the loop,
- [Dead Code Elimination](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#dce-dead-code-elimination): removes code that is not useful.

> What? How dare the optimizer mangle my code so?

The optimizer operates under the so-called *as-if* rule. This basic rule allows the optimizer to perform any transformation which does *not* change the output of the program. That is, it should not change the *observable behavior* of the program in general.

On top of that, a few changes are generally explicitly allowed. The most obvious being that the run-time is expected to shrink, this in turn means that thread interleaving may differ, and some languages give even more wiggle room.

> I used `black_box`!

What is `black_box`? It's a function whose definition is specifically *opaque* to the optimizer. This has some implications on the optimizations the compiler is allowed to perform since it may have side-effects. This therefore mean:

- the transformed code must perform the very same number of calls to `black_box` than the original code,
- the transformed code must perform said calls in the same order with regard to the passed in arguments,
- no assumption can be made on the value returned by `black_box`.

Thus, surgical use of `black_box` can foil certain optimizations. Blind use, however, may not foil the right ones.

> What optimizations am I running afoul of?

Let's start from the naive code:

```
#[bench]
fn rust_get(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let (hash, mut keys): (HashMap<String, usize>, _) =
        get_random_hash(&HashMap::with_capacity, &rust_insert_fn);

    b.iter(|| {
        for k in keys.drain(..) {
            hash.get(&k);
        }
    });
}
```

The assumption is that the loop inside `b.iter()` will iterate over all keys and perform a `hash.get()` for each of them:

1. The result of `hash.get()` is unused,
2. `hash.get()` is a *pure* function, meaning that is has no side-effect.

Thus, this loop can be rewritten as:

```
b.iter(|| { for k in keys.drain(..) {} })
```

We are running afoul of *Dead Code Elimination* (or some variant): the code serves no purpose, thus it is eliminated.

It may even be that the compiler is smart enough to realize that `for k in keys.drain(..) {}` can be optimized into `drop(keys)`.

A surgical application of `black_box` can, however, foil DCE:

```
b.iter(|| {
    for k in keys.drain(..) {
        black_box(hash.get(&k));
    }
});
```

As per the effects of `black_box` described above:

- the loop can no longer be optimized out, as it would change the number of calls to `black_box`,
- each call to `black_box` must be performed with the expected argument.

There is still *one* possible hurdle: *Constant Propagation*. Specifically if the compiler realizes that all keys yield the same value, it could optimize out `hash.get(&k)` and replace it by said value.

This can be achieved by obfuscating the keys: `let mut keys = black_box(keys);`, as you did above, or the map. If you were to benchmark an empty map, the latter would be necessary, here they are equal.

We thus get:

```
#[bench]
fn rust_get(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let (hash, keys): (HashMap<String, usize>, _) =
        get_random_hash(&HashMap::with_capacity, &rust_insert_fn);
    let mut keys = test::black_box(keys);

    b.iter(|| {
        for k in keys.drain(..) {
            test::black_box(hash.get(&k));
        }
    });
}
```

> A final tip.

Benchmarks are complicated enough that you should be extra careful to only benchmark what you wish to benchmark.

In this particular case, there are two method calls:

- `keys.drain()`,
- `hash.get()`.

Since the benchmark name suggests, to me, that what you aim for is to measure the performance of `get`, I can only assume that the call to `keys.drain(..)` is a mistake.

Thus, the benchmark really should be:

```
#[bench]
fn rust_get(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let (hash, keys): (HashMap<String, usize>, _) =
        get_random_hash(&HashMap::with_capacity, &rust_insert_fn);
    let keys = test::black_box(keys);

    b.iter(|| {
        for k in &keys {
            test::black_box(hash.get(k));
        }
    });
}
```

In this instance, this is even more critical in that the closure passed to `b.iter()` is expected to run multiple times: if you drain the keys the first time, what's left afterward? An empty `Vec`...

... which may actually be all that is really happening here; since `b.iter()` runs the closure until its time stabilizes, it may just be draining the `Vec` in the first run and then time an empty loop.

Comment: I tried your suggestion of calling black_box on the result of hash.get and I still get 0ns as the running time. I also find it strange that the delete benchmark takes 1 ns because the delete should be modifying the hash table so it cannot be optimized out.

Comment: @user1413793: You are still using `keys.drain(..)`, and that's a trap. As mentioned in my answer, the closure you pass to `b.iter` is ran multiple times to get an accurate measurement. The problem is that `keys.drain(..)` will empty the vector of `keys` at the first iteration and all successive runs will be just a single branch "empty => nothing to do", for which 1ns is a reasonable time.

Comment: In that case, is it possible to set up a benchmark and only time one part of it and have the setup run on every iteration?

Comment: @user1413793: In this specific case, this is unnecessary (just iterate over `&keys`), but... [everyone is actually wondering how to have one setup per iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44344832/how-can-i-benchmark-code-that-mutates-the-setup-data), you're not alone.