# How can I benchmark code that mutates the setup data?

Tags: rust, benchmarking

The current implementation of the built-in benchmarking tool appears to run  the code inside the `iter` call multiple times for each time the setup code outside the `iter` is run. When the code being benchmarked modifies the setup data, subsequent iterations of the benchmarked code are no longer benchmarking the same thing.

As a concrete example, I am benchmarking how fast it takes to remove values from a `Vec`:

```
#![feature(test)]

extern crate test;

use test::Bencher;

#[bench]
fn clearing_a_vector(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let mut things = vec![1];
    b.iter(|| {
        assert!(!things.is_empty());
        things.clear();
    });
}
```

This will fail:

```
test clearing_a_vector ... thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: !things.is_empty()', src/lib.rs:11
```

Performing a similar benchmark of `push`ing an element onto the vector shows that the `iter` closure was executed nearly 980 million times (depending on how fast the closure is). The results could be *very* misleading if there's a single run that does what I expect and millions more that don't.

Tests were run with Rust nightly 1.19.0 (f89d8d184 2017-05-30)

Comment: This is a repost of another question that was here earlier but seems to have been deleted. I still want to know the answer though!

Comment: @ljedrz the time taken inside the `iter` block is what is used for benchmarking. If I add the setup to that block, the time to perform the setup will be counted as part of the benchmark; I'd no longer be timing just the relevant function (`clear`) but also unrelated code.

Comment: There appears to be a [`bench::run_once`](https://manishearth.github.io/rust-internals-docs/src/test/lib.rs.html#1588) method which would allow to run a single iteration of the benchmark. I'm not sure how to get a statistically representative sample with this however...

Comment: Is there any better way than bench::run_once ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [pew](https://crates.io/crates/pew), a recently published crate for benchmarking rust code. It allows you to do one time set up that is cloned into every benchmark, or manually run set up by pausing/resuming the benchmark.

This library is in very early phases, but it might be what you're looking for. Contributions are always welcome.